# Transferring the query to the xml file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

[enter image description config xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYRMv.png)

[enter image description for use  xml file in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFWvG.png)

This program uses "jpa", but for a series of tasks, I had to write a query, and as long as the queries were above the method, the program was executed, but after
Transferring the query to the program's xml program failed

My goal is to transfer the queries to the xml file in the spring boot jpa project

my error is

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-13T12:00:43.357+03:30 ERROR 16100 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employerService': Error creating bean with name 'employerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employerDao': Error creating bean with name 'employerDao' defined in com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); No property 'update' found for type 'Employer'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.HouseCleaningServiceCompanyApplication.main(HouseCleaningServiceCompanyApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employerService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employerDao': Error creating bean with name 'employerDao' defined in com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); No property 'update' found for type 'Employer'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:712) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:692) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:127) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1397) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employerDao' defined in com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); No property 'update' found for type 'Employer'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:709) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); No property 'update' found for type 'Employer'
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:88) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:357) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:279) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:229) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:113) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:132) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract void com.example.house_cleaning_service_company.employer.dao.EmployerDao.update(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.Long); No property 'update' found for type 'Employer'
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:124) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:258) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:111) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'update' found for type 'Employer'
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:423) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:399) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:352) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:334) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:242) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:243) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:372) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
    ... 60 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/25agP.png
```

Comment: How do you run the query?

Comment: https://nieldw.medium.com/jpa-spring-boot-will-not-search-for-meta-inf-persistence-xml-f28f14444d6d

Comment: How do you run the query?    for example I wrote my query in xml file   that has name   for use that must make method without parameter in "dao"
   but don't work

Comment: I set two picture pleas see those thanks

Comment: "JPA: Spring Boot will not search for `META-INF/persistence.xml`" (is the title(+solution) of my linked article;)